# How to neatly align long equations one below each other

Tags: equations, align

I have seven different equations which I want to left align.

Below is the code I am using to align the equations:

```
\begin{equation}
\phi_{1} \; = \; n_{20} + n_{02}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\phi_{2} \; = \; (n_{20} - n_{02})^2 + 4n_{11}^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\phi_{3} \; = \; n_{30} - n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} - n_{03}^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\phi_{4} \; = \; n_{30} + n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} + n_{03}^2
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
\phi_{5} \; = \; (n_{30} - 3n_{12})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) -3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2] + (3n_{12} - n_{03})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_ {12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2]
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
\phi_{6} \; = \; (n_{20} - n_{02})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2] + 4n_{11}(n_{30} + n_{12})(n_{21} + n_{03})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\phi_{7} \; = \; (3n_{21} - n_{03})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - 3(n_{21} + n_{03})^2] + (3n_{12} - n_{30})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03}^2)]
\end{equation}
```

I want the equations to be left align and evenly spaced on each line, i.e. if an equation is too long it should go on to the next line.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) use `align` to collect them all (no real need for `multline`, break a line in align instead. Don't use `\; = \;`, it is a wast of time and you end up with a setup looking uneven.

Comment: (3) for left aligned equations (to the whole document) use the class option `fleqn`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks...i don't want all the equations in the document to be left align. Just the above ones

Comment: Equation line breaking: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines For left aligning equations: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54478/how-to-left-align-a-set-of-equations

Comment: @Avi Maikoo: To left-align only a group of equations, please see the answer to a [recent similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340204/left-align-equation-in-equation-enviroment/340208#340208).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `align` environment seems right, plus additional line breaks for  equations 5, 6, and 7; the second halves of these equations are indented (by the amount of `\quad`) relative to the first halves. Note that I've performed alignment on the `=` symbols, not full left-alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\phi_{1} &= n_{20} + n_{02}\\
\phi_{2} &= (n_{20} - n_{02})^2 + 4n_{11}^2\\
\phi_{3} &= n_{30} - n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} - n_{03}^2\\
\phi_{4} &= n_{30} + n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} + n_{03}^2\\
\phi_{5} &= (n_{30} - 3n_{12})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) -3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2] \notag\\
&\quad+ (3n_{12} - n_{03})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_ {12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2]\\
\phi_{6} &= (n_{20} - n_{02})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2] \notag\\
&\quad+ 4n_{11}(n_{30} + n_{12})(n_{21} + n_{03})\\
\phi_{7} &= (3n_{21} - n_{03})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - 3(n_{21} + n_{03})^2] \notag\\
&\quad+ (3n_{12} - n_{30})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03}^2)]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align` and `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\phi_{1} &= n_{20} + n_{02}
\\
\phi_{2} &= (n_{20} - n_{02})^2 + 4n_{11}^2
\\
\phi_{3} &= n_{30} - n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} - n_{03}^2
\\
\phi_{4} &= n_{30} + n_{12}^2 + 3n_{21} + n_{03}^2
\\
\begin{split}
\phi_{5} &= (n_{30} - 3n_{12})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) -3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2] \\
         &\qquad+ (3n_{12} - n_{03})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_ {12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2]
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
\phi_{6} &= (n_{20} - n_{02})[(n_{30} + n_{12}^2) - (n_{21} + n_{03})^2] \\
         &\qquad+ 4n_{11}(n_{30} + n_{12})(n_{21} + n_{03})
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
\phi_{7} &= (3n_{21} - n_{03})(n_{30} + n_{12})[(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - 3(n_{21} + n_{03})^2] \\
         &\qquad+ (3n_{12} - n_{30})(n_{21} + n_{03})[3(n_{30} + n_{12})^2 - (n_{21} + n_{03}^2)]
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the difference with just `align` and `\notag`? The equation number in a `split` is vertically centered (unless the `tbtags` option is passed to `amsmath`).

Comment: How can I make align align left instead of right?

Comment: @GerardoZinno Isn't this left aligned?